# how to get output from curl request to a file even if status code is 400?

Tags: bash, shell, curl

if I do a request via curl to a normal site I may direct the output to a file with header data and stuff like this:

Command:

```
curl -is www.google.de > temp.txt
```

Output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 29 Feb 2012 16:49:09 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=16ad7441d475580e:FF=0:TM=1330534149:LM=1330534149:S=2MpGe04BWQ8Kn3P7; expires=Fri, 28-Feb-2014 16:49:09 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.de
Set-Cookie: NID=57=BCgUcqNQU5dMWcBEMP85saDNUdXg2_LG4eZFmS-yr1W38UyTNuB8BU8iiOOsK2747WGJG99uJDW6t8N78D4QzBma7q2EmKQ69-gCjOysFNLGFggrvMxcqEOl7p1hemeQ; expires=Thu, 30-Aug-2012 16:49:09 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.de; HttpOnly
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

<!doctype html><html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage"><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"><meta itemprop="image" content="/images/google_favicon_128.png"><title>Google</title><script>window.google={kEI:"BVdOT7OzE8_ktQaqk-WGDw",getEI:function(a){var d;while(a&&!(a.getAttribute&&(d=a.getAttribute("eid"))))a=a.parentNode;return d||google.kEI},https:function(){return window.location.protocol=="https:"},kEXPI:"31701,33551,34324,34904,35055,35091,36604,36683,36716,36946,37017,37055,37126",kCSI:{e:"31701,33551,34324,34904,35055,35091,36604,36683,36716,36946,37017,37055,37126",ei:"BVdOT7OzE8_ktQaqk-WGDw"},authuser:0,
ml:function(){},kHL:"de",time:function(){return(new Date).getTime()},log:function(a,d,f,h){var e=new Image,g=google,k=g.lc,i=g.li,m="";e.onerror=(e.onload=(e.onabort=function(){delete k[i]}));k[i]=e;if(!f&&d.search("&ei=")==-1)m="&ei="+google.getEI(h);var j=f||"/gen_204?atyp=i&ct="+a+"&cad="+d+m+"&zx="+google.time(),b=/^http:/i;if(b.test(j)&&google.https()){google.ml(new Error("GLMM"),false,{src:j});
delete k[i];return}e.src=j;g.li=i...
```

When I do the same request to an url, where the response will have an status code 400, I will get an error that will be prompted to the shell and the file will be empty:

`curl -is https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=SOME_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=SOME_CLIENT_SECRET&code=notavalidcode&redirect_uri=SOME_REDIRECT_URI > temp.txt`

Is there a way to prompt the result to a file also if I get an status code 400?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

wrap the url with `"`

```
kent$  curl -is "https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=SOME_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=SOME_CLIENT_SECRET&code=notavalidcode&redirect_uri=SOME_REDIRECT_URI" > temp.txt

kent$  cat temp.txt 
HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established


HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache, private, no-store
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 29 Feb 2012 16:59:16 GMT
Expires: Wed, 29 Feb 2012 16:59:16 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx/0.8.52
Content-Length: 26
Connection: keep-alive

{"error":"invalid_client"}
```